# Is there a way I can install devDependencies ONLY for bower packages?

Tags: bower, gulp

I have my custom bower packages deployed to different locations based on environment. That is during development stage, package source is different from what it is in application's production phase.

So I thought distinguishing these package sources with the help of devDependencies and dependencies section in my bower.json file. But I can't find a way to install DEV only dependencies. Though I can see to install Production ONLY dependencies.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible OOB. But can be done with the help of [main-bower-files](https://www.npmjs.org/package/main-bower-files/).